# the audio service is not running

Tags: windows-10, audio

I cannot play any sound from my laptop or from my headset (logitech g430) and when i click on realtek hd audio it says no devices are installed. when i go to device manager intel(R) Display audio and Logitech G430 Gaming Headset are listed and are said to be working properly. There are two Realtek High Definition Audio but the second one has a yellow triangle with a "!" and its status says "this device cannot start. (code 10). the request is not supported. i've tried starting the device manually and made sure it is set to an automatic start and i've tried restarting my computer. I've also checked all of my drivers and they are all up to date. I am also using windows 10

Comment: I had to download new drivers directly from realtek to get my audio running, though Win10 said everything was up to date.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, though oddly enough it worked at first -- on the first run, it worked fine, but after a restart (by which I mean a random bluescreen) it couldn't find it.